# Java Spring Data @Query with @OneToMany relation returns no result

Tags: java, spring, jpa, assertion

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    ...

@Entity
public class Address extends BaseEntity {

    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    ...
```

And the following repository interface class:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query("select c from Customer c join c.addresses a where (a.city = :cityName)")
    List<Customer> findByCity(@Param("cityName")String city);

}
```

Now, I'm trying to run the following integration test, but it fails and I absolutely don't know why. Unfortunately, I'm a beginner with Spring and I'm trying to learn it ;-)

```
@Test
public void testFindCustomerByCity() {
    Customer customer = new Customer("Max", "Tester");
    Address address = new Address("Street", "1", "12345", "City");
    HashSet<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    addresses.add(address);
    customer.setAddresses(addresses);
    Customer savedCustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);
    Assert.assertTrue(savedCustomer.getId() > 0);

    List<Customer> customerList = customerRepository.findByCity("City");
    Assert.assertThat(customerList.size(), is(1));
}
```

The error message is:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected: is <1>
>        but: was <0>

Why is the result empty. Is my test setting wrong? The entity relation?
It would be fine, if you can help me.

Comment: You haven't set the customer on the address only the address in the customer.

Comment: @M ok I've added `address.setCustomer(customer);` and it works... but sincerely I don't understand it... I thought, it's enough to give the parent entity the children entities. Maybe you can explain it shortly or give me a link url as hint... Anyway, thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: You have an address with a `null` customer where as you specified that the relation is managed by the customer property in address. If that isn't set how should the database know that there is a relation. Also doing a `setAddresses` is a really bad way of adding addresses to a customer. Remove that method and create an `addAddress` method in which you probably manage the relationship.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you weren't setting the `customer` in `address`, were the addresses saved to the database without a customer foreign key? Or was the problem with the find query? would be good to know that for anyone visiting this question at a later date.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear without a customer foreign key

Comment: Please what if I want to get all adresses of the customer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on the `addresses` field in the `Customer` entity. This basically means that the relationship is managed by the value in the `customer` field in the `Address` entity.

In your test code you are only setting the addresses on the customer but not the customer on the address. It is still null, so probably there are 2 records in the database but there is no relation. Hence nothing will be returned from your query.

Setting the collection like you do with `setAddresses` is a really bad way of doing things in a JPA environment (when you do this on an already existing instance you will overwrite the persistent collection). Remove the `setAddresses` method and create an `addAddress` method on the `Customer` instead.

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    // No setter, only a getter which returns an immutable collection
    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.addresses);
    }

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        address.setCustomer(this);
        this.addresses.add(address);
    }

}
```

This also cleans up your test code a little.

```
@Test
public void testFindCustomerByCity() {
    Customer customer = new Customer("Max", "Tester");
    customer.addAddress(new Address("Street", "1", "12345", "City"));
    Customer savedCustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);

    Assert.assertTrue(savedCustomer.getId() > 0);

    List<Customer> customerList = customerRepository.findByCity("City");
    Assert.assertThat(customerList.size(), is(1));
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use query method like this. Use **underscore** (_) to get property child.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByAddresses_City(String city);
}
```

Comment: The underscore shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The underscore is necessary because the city is not a Customer property rather the property of it's child item (Address).

Comment: The underscore is not strictly necessary. If we have findByAdressesCity it will search for AddressesCity first and then will start cutting the CamelCase from the right(!) so then it will search for Adresses.City and have a hit. More documntation about this can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions